# How to deploy a FastAPI app using PostgreSQL as a database on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, fastapi

I developed a FastAPI app in a Virtual Environment using an SQLite database but deployed it on Heroku with a PostgresSQL database on Heroku as suggested in the [tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/). Although it worked on my PC, adding PostegresSQL as an addon & replacing the value of `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL` in the `database.py` broke everything. Note that I've properly frozen the dependencies on the `requirements.txt` file. Yet I can't figure out what went wrong.

For further clarification, I've pushed my code to GitHub & it can be accessed at this repository - [Self_calculation](https://github.com/mrk24251/Self_calculation).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Postgres Addon on Heroku, probably your solution is simple.

Use `os.environ` to get the connection parameters , don't try to connect directly, it's Heroku's recommended solution from [**Heroku Postgres**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python)

```
import os

DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
```

Answer (score 1):

I just need to run this:
1)`heroku git:remote -a my_heroku_app_name`

2)`heroku logs --tail`

after that I could see my problem.
In my case I forgot to change postgres url in alembic.ini file

Comment: It's always better to accept the answer which worked for you. Also when you write an answer, explain what went wrong & what specific lines of code are doing. This helps the other person stumbling across your answer with better clarity.